# How to add a daemon.json file in docker ubuntu?

Tags: docker

I don't know how to add a daemon json file in this /etc/docker/daemon.json location

I tried with this command dockerd --config-file /etc/docker/daemon.json and it is giving error that daemon.json is not present in current location

Answer (score 0):

often the file does not exist and you will need to create it. In recent docker versions it contains just the following

```json
{
    "log-level":        "error"
}
```

To create it, you may run (with privileges)

```
sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

and paste the content above and all changes you need to do. For users with docker in snap, the used daemon file can be found in `/var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json`, so edit that one. To save press `CTRL`+`O`, exit with `CTRL`+`X`. Of course, you can use any other text editor to do this.